# Android: trouble using Thread and Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, handler, message

I have an Activity from which a new thread is called (for downloading same data).

In my Activty, I implemented a Handler that receives a message from the aforementioned thread.
When that message is received some code is executed (this code will not impact the UI).

My question is:

If my actvity is in background (state pause or stop) what happens when message sent from the thread is received? Can the activity manage the message received and execute some code? And what happen if this code try to update the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know about Android. You can update activity content if still is in background. But we should be sure that how long activity will be in background. It can be killed in extreme low memory situation. So in

**HandleMessage() of Handler, Check if(Activity.this!=null){Update UI}**

Comment: Thank you @Sameer. Yes, the other doubt is when I need to exec code that not impacts to UI. Can this code be executed even if my activity is in background?

Comment: Yes it can be executed if your activity is in background. but it should exists Mark it as answer if it solve your doubts